# UIViewPropertyAnimator in UINavigationController

Tags: swift, uivisualeffectview, uiviewpropertyanimator

I have a UIViewPropertyAnimator setted on a UIVisualEffectView in order to animate its blurriness with a slider. This UIViewPropertyAnimator seems to have no more effect when :

1. Play with the slider and adjust blurriness
2. The view controller that presents this blurry view is embedded in a navigation controller
3. I push a new controller on this navigation controller
4. Back to blurry view controller
5. The slider is not working anymore

I've tried to play with stopAnimation & finishAnimation function from the animator with no luck. Is it the expected behaviour ? I guess I could solve this issue by completly removing and resetting the blur and its animator with correct value when needed (like on viewWillAppear, didDisappear) but that seems so wrong... !

[github source code](https://github.com/nelsballs/AnimateBlurRadius)

Comment: Please check my answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42608071/4572536

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm ! Thanks !