# UIViewPropertyAnimator does not update the view when expected

Tags: swift, uiviewpropertyanimator

Here is a Swift playground code, which I also tested in the iOS Simulator just to be sure that it's not an issue of Playground.

Setting the property `fractionComplete` result in change of state from `inactive` to `active`. However as shown below the view is not updated for the first two calls. Only the third call magically updates the view.

This behavior is confusing and I seek for explanation.

```
let liveView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 50))
liveView.backgroundColor = .white

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = liveView

let square = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
square.backgroundColor = .red

liveView.addSubview(square)

let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator.init(duration: 5, curve: .easeIn)

animator.addAnimations {

    square.frame.origin.x = 350
}

// State: inactive
// Does nothing, position is at 0.0
DispatchQueue.main.async {

    animator.fractionComplete = 0.5
}

// State: active
// Stil does nothing, position is at 0.0
DispatchQueue.main.async {

    animator.fractionComplete = 0.5
}

// Updates from 0.0 to 0.75 - Why now?
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) { 

    animator.fractionComplete = 0.75
}
```

**Update:** Putting this two lines before the first call seems to be a workaround for the issue.

```
animator.startAnimation()
animator.pauseAnimation()
```

I assume it's an internal bug. [rdar://30856746](https://openradar.appspot.com/30856746)

Comment: Looks like an internal bug related to DispatchQueue, for sure. Haven't seen it before. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @DanielLarsson Honestly, I don't think it's a bug in `DispatchQueue` at least not in the object itself. I only used it to showcase that the `fractionComplete` property does nothing when its set while being `inactive`. I assume that Apple might use `DispatchQueue` internally inside `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, but for some reason they messed something up, so the `fractionComplete` property does not work as documented/expected.