# How do you programmatically change the alpha of a UIVisualEffectView in a NavigationBar?

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a scroll view that I'm using to control the alpha of other elements depending on how far down the view the user scrolls.

First, I set up the blur view. **Alpha here doesn't seem to take, firstly**

```
var effect: UIBlurEffectStyle = .light
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    effect = .prominent
}
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: effect))
blurView.alpha = 0
if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
    blurView.frame = navigationBar.bounds
}
self.blurView = blurView
```

[image: navbar]

Then in my `UIScrollViewDelegate`:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        var alpha = (scrollView.contentOffset.y / 200)
        alpha = alpha > 1.0 ? 1.0 : alpha

        blurView?.alpha = alpha
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working either.

Any advice on how to achieve this effect? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look as if you've added the blurView to the view hierarchy anywhere.

Comment: I'm not, true. But it's showing up, which I've thought is curious for a few days. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uivisualeffectview) you can find:

> When using the UIVisualEffectView class, avoid alpha values that are
>   less than 1.

[image]

In fact you should obtain also a warning:

```
[Warning] <UIVisualEffectView 0x7af7a3b0> is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1.
```

**P.S.:** *Pay attention, what I mean is that you can change the alpha of the visual effects but the view could appear as simply partially transparent rather than blurred.*

If you don't believe in this documentation, you can test my little example below to a blank project and you can see that, if you change alpha value, your effect stop to work correctly:

(You can find all the project below to my **GitHUB** repository [here](https://github.com/aornano/UIVisualEffectView-in-a-NavigationBar-changing-alpha-))

Prepare in a blank project a navigationController connected to a viewController like this:

[image]

Put a generic image with an `UIImageView` to the view of your viewController, like this image:

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!
    var effect: UIBlurEffectStyle = .light
    var blurEffect : UIBlurEffect!
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // This code make more transparent our navigation
        if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
            navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
            navigationBar.tintColor = .white
            let textAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
            navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
            navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
            navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.3, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.3)
            navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            effect = .prominent
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
            let noEffectView = UIVisualEffectView.init(frame: navigationBar.bounds)
            self.blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: effect)
            self.blurView = noEffectView
            navigationBar.addSubview(self.blurView)
            // This line below to don't blur buttons and title
            navigationBar.sendSubview(toBack: self.blurView)
            // Apply the effect:
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.applyBlur), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }
    func applyBlur() {
        print("Apply the blur effect..")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.2, animations: {
            self.blurView.effect = self.blurEffect
        }, completion:{ (finished: Bool) in
            // Make test with a simple timer:
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.3, target: self, selector: #selector(self.changeAlpha), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        })
    }
    func changeAlpha() {
        let startNum:CGFloat = 0.0; let stopNum:CGFloat = 200.0
        let randomNum = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(startNum - stopNum) + min(startNum, stopNum)
        var alpha = (randomNum / 200)
        alpha = alpha > 1.0 ? 1.0 : alpha
        print("we change alpha to : \(alpha)")
        self.blurView.alpha = alpha
    }
}
```

**Output with the blur effect:**

[image]

**Output during alpha changes:**

[image]

### A solution:

**Probably you don't want to change the alpha value but the amount of blur effect during the scrolling** so the solution could be to use the new `fractionComplete` of `UIViewPropertyAnimator` property available only from **iOS 10.0** (as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42608071/1894067) other SO answer)

```
import UIKit
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!
    var effect: UIBlurEffectStyle = .light
    var blurEffect : UIBlurEffect!
    var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator!
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // This code make more transparent our navigation
        if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
            navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
            navigationBar.tintColor = .white
            let textAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
            navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
            navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
            navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.3, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.3)
            navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            effect = .prominent
            if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
                let noEffectView = UIVisualEffectView.init(frame: navigationBar.bounds)
                self.blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: effect)
                self.blurView = noEffectView
                navigationBar.addSubview(self.blurView)
                // This line below to don't blur buttons and title
                navigationBar.sendSubview(toBack: self.blurView)
                // Apply the effect:
                Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.applyBlur), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            }
    }
    func applyBlur() {
        print("Apply the blur effect..")
        animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, curve: .linear)
        self.blurView.effect = self.blurEffect
        animator.addAnimations {
            self.blurView.effect = nil
        }
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.3, target: self, selector: #selector(self.changeBlurFraction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
    func changeBlurFraction() {
        let startNum:CGFloat = 0.0; let stopNum:CGFloat = 200.0
        let randomNum = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(startNum - stopNum) + min(startNum, stopNum)
        var blurFraction = (randomNum / 200)
        blurFraction = blurFraction > 1.0 ? 1.0 : blurFraction
        print("we change the blur fraction to : \(blurFraction)")
        animator.fractionComplete = blurFraction
    }
}
```

As you can see this change the blur effect not the alpha and every time the timer is fired you can see a different value of blur to your navigationBar.

The trick is to apply the blur effect and add a new animation to report the effect to nil but everytime with a new "fraction" to change the animation to that exact value of blur.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: GitHUB project [here](https://github.com/aornano/UIVisualEffectView-in-a-NavigationBar-changing-alpha-)

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer, Alessandro

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5.0. Just use code below:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

It changes '0.85 alpha effect' with solid color with alpha = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Alpha blending of a `UIVisualEffectView` is broken as of iOS 10, along with layer masking, due to internal change to the implementation by Apple.

I'd suggest using a `UIView​Property​Animator` object to transition from the actual effect (`.prominent`, in your case) to `nil`, and then manually set the `fractionComplete` to be the alpha value. It will give you a much better effect and allow you to interactively change the effect.